# Opacity for Chrome browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, opacity

I need to set an HTML input type= "file" object's opacity in Chrome.
In IE, it looks perfect as i have used filter as below :

```
 style="position: absolute; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=0);
```

Same need to do for Chrome. Can anyone suggest how i use opacity filter for chrome?
[image: How it looks in chrome]

So i need to hide this "Choose File" from the screen. I chose width=70px so that it can be clickable at a larger part.
This is the input type i am using :

```
<input type="file" name="AttachLink"  style="position: absolute; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=0); imgobject.style.opacity=0; width:70px; height:50px; cursor: hand; left:-26px;" title="Add File Attachment" onChange="getWeblink();" size="40" float="right">
```

Comment: It's just `opacity:0`... not `imgobject.style.opacity=0`...

Answer (score 2):

Use `Opacity` property of css. You have to use `opacity:0` for your scenario. `Opacity` property take value from `0 to 1` where `filter:Alpha` takes value from `0 to 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
opacity:0;
```

An alternative is

```
visibility:hidden;
```

if you want the width to stay there.